# Not finding import Utils.*;

Tags: java, sql

i want to import the following:
import Utils.*;

It Simply does not find that and i have no Plan how to solve that. Can you help  me?

Comment: Do you mean java.util? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html

Comment: We can't possibly know either, since we have no idea what this package is, what it's supposed to contain, where it's supposed to come from. All we know is that it doesn't respect the basic Java naming conventions, which is not a good sign.

Comment: Ok, i am going to try that

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
I needed to import a external .jar File into the classpath. After doöing this, my code worked without any issues and i could continue programming :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `import java.util.*;`. Looks like you have the incorrect package name. Though this is guessing what package you are trying to import based on a single word...